# android telephone call - android.telecom.Call

Tags: java, android, android-phone-call

Excuse me if I have made a mistake - this is my first post! I am also new to android & Java.

I have being trying to write an app which will allow me to make a call, and monitor the call status. From what I have found, the 'normal' way to do this does something like this:

    `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);`

Using this technique, you don't actually get an indication that the call has been answered, which I need to know for my app.
I have had a look around for other solutions and have found the class android.telecom.Call. This looks like it will do what I need, but I haven't been able to implement an example, or find one online. Is anyone able to help me with this, or point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance for any advice, and apologies again if I have asked in the wrong place!

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Im using same code for calling with intent as you(But in xamarin).
You can monitor state with PhoneStateListener

```
 public override void OnCallStateChanged(CallState state, string incomingNumber)
    {
        base.OnCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
```

All you need is track state changing.

Call started:  CallState.Idle -> CallState.Offhook

Call ended: CallState.Offhook -> CallState.Idle

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My initial attempt at this did use PhoneStateListener, however (as far as I can tell), it will only show 3 state changes : CALL_STATE_IDLE, CALL_STATE_RINGING and CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK cannot differentiate between if an outgoing call is off hook, or if it has been answered

Comment: Oh, then yes, state tracking want help you.